# Parse HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to send a POST request and try to process the output, more specifically, parse the JSON string that is inside a (well, the only) `<pre>` element.

This is what I came up with:

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log("body: "+body)
    var inside = body.match("<pre>(.*)</pre>");
    console.log("inside: "+inside);
    // what I really want:
    var obj = JSON.parse(inside);
    }
})
```

Here is the output:

```
body: 


<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div><pre>{
&nbsp;&quot;variable&quot;: [
&nbsp;{
...
&nbsp;&nbsp;]
}
</pre></div>  
</body>
</html>

inside: null
```

I get the `body` as expected, but `inside` is null. How can I read it correctly?

Also, I guess I need to sanitize those `&nbsp;`s and `&quot;`s for `JSON.parse()` to work. Although that might be another question, any help on this would also be much appreciated :)

Thanks,

Comment: @jeff, are you using jquery or plain xhr request? because xhr has a property called `responseType = "document";`. If you set it, your response will return a`.responseXML` property with an already decoded document. Anyway, if you still wans to use regex, you'll have to decode your string (to remove the special chars) and then JSON parse it.

Comment: @mrlew I'm doing this from Node.js. The duplicate suggestion solved the problem of parsing it. Thanks,